# Is it easier to publish in certain areas of mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, publishing

I was wondering whether there are areas of mathematics that it is easier to publish in than in others. The reason I'm asking this question is not because I would then want to do research there, but just because it seemed like people working on, say, PDEs, in general have more publications (so just going by the numbers) than those working in, say, the field of topology. A professor of mine also mentioned passingly once when commenting on some of the publications that that might have just been an area where people don't people publish as often.

Is this a misconception or is there a grain of truth to it? If so, a) what do you think the "easier to publish in" and what the "harder to publish in"  areas are, and b) what are the reasons for the easier/harder road to publication?

Comment: It's definitely true.

Comment: Aside from cultural differences, it's definitely true that some areas are more "thoroughly mined" than others. You mention PDEs, and they benefit from several factors that makes publication easier: they are of tremendous practical importance, there is no satisfying general theory, and many different kinds of PDEs can be studied independently and in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in comments:

> It's definitely true. –  user35603 Apr 14 at 6:55

and

> Aside from cultural differences, it's definitely true that some areas are more "thoroughly mined" than others. You mention PDEs, and they benefit from several factors that makes publication easier: they are of tremendous practical importance, there is no satisfying general theory, and many different kinds of PDEs can be studied independently and in parallel. –  user7530 Apr 14 at 7:03